# Count Inversion per Element

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, count, mergesort

I want to count the number of inversions *per element* for some list. 
If `i < j` and `list[i] > list[j]` then the pair `(i, j)` is an inversion. Many algorithms count the total number of those pairs, while I'd like to count, for all elements of some list, how often those elements are part of an inversion pair.

Consider e.g. this list: `[4, 2, 3, 1]`

There are five inversion pairs: `(4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)`. I know you can get the element counts via a nested for loop (or using vectorization) like:

```py
import numpy as np
lst = np.array([4,2,3,1])
inv_count = np.zeros(lst.size)

for i in np.arange(lst.size - 1):
  idx = np.where(lst[i] > lst[(i+1):])[0] + i + 1
  inv_count[idx] += 1
  inv_count[i] += idx.size
```

yielding the correct result

```
array([3., 2., 2., 3.])
```

But that is running in `O(n^2)` (I think) and I was wondering if it can be solved more efficiently.

I know mergesort as e.g. shown below is frequently used for counting total inversions in `O(n log n)`, but I am not sure how I could adopt it to count per element instead?

```py
def mergeSortInversions(arr):
  if len(arr) == 1:
    return arr, 0
  else:
    a = arr[:len(arr)//2]
    b = arr[len(arr)//2:]
    a, ai = mergeSortInversions(a)
    b, bi = mergeSortInversions(b)
    c = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    inversions = 0 + ai + bi
  while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    if a[i] <= b[j]:
      c.append(a[i])
      i += 1
    else:
      c.append(b[j])
      j += 1
      inversions += (len(a)-i)
  c += a[i:]
  c += b[j:]
  return c, inversions
```

Comment: I'd ask you to be more specific about what you mean by an *inversion. Although, it seems you cannot do better than worst case O(n^2) because in the worst case you can have O(n^2) inversions.

Comment: I've hopefully clarified the question @OlivierMelançon Total count of inversions can be found in O(nlogn) using mergesort

Comment: You can still squeeze this in merge sort. Just keep track of the original indices where you seem to have an inversion pair. Then you can map those indices with the original array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions `combinations()` and `filter()` to build the list with inversions:

```
from itertools import combinations

l = [4, 2, 3, 1]

list(filter(lambda x: x[0] > x[1], combinations(l, 2)))
# [(4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

You can use `defaultdict()` to count inversions:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict

l = [4, 2, 3, 1]

dd = defaultdict(int)

for i, j in combinations(l, 2):
    if i > j:
        dd[i] += 1
        dd[j] += 1

print(dd)
# defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3})
```

Comment: True, but that is also a nested for loop, just hidden behind functions

Comment: @eok Built-in functions are faster than user-defined functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could explore np.greater.outer().  The outer method of a ufunc.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([ 4, 2, 3, 1])
```

Generate a square array with a[i]>a[j] for all i and j

```
arr = np.greater.outer(a,a)*1
arr
Out[24]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

We're only interested in the top right triangle.

```
arr = np.triu(arr)
arr
Out[25]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])

arr += arr.T # add the transposition.  arr is symmetrical about the diagonal.
arr  
Out[9]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Sum rows to get the counts.

```
arr.sum(axis = 0)
Out[28]: array([3, 2, 2, 3])
```

All the loops are hidden in the outer method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @Andrew Scott's comment, this is the change required:

```
import numpy as np
def mergeSortInversions(arr, counts):
  if len(arr) == 1:
    return arr, counts
  else:
    a = arr[:len(arr)//2]
    b = arr[len(arr)//2:]
    a, ai = mergeSortInversions(a, counts)
    b, bi = mergeSortInversions(b, counts)    
    c = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    inversions = ai + bi

  while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
      if a[i] <= b[j]:
          c = np.concatenate([c, a[i, None]])
          i += 1
      else:
          c = np.concatenate([c, b[j, None]])
          inversions[a[i:].astype(np.int) - 1] += 1
          inversions[b[j].astype(np.int) - 1]  += (len(a)-i)
          j += 1

  c = np.concatenate([c, a[i:]])
  c = np.concatenate([c, b[j:]])
  return c, inversions
```